# Android forceWifiUsage is not working on Android pie(9)

Tags: java, android

I have react-native component to connect wifi [react-native-android-wifi](https://github.com/devstepbcn/react-native-android-wifi), which provide an option to `wifi.forceWifiUsage(true);` enable only when communicating with the device via wifi, but this is not working on android 9(pie), following is java method

```
public void forceWifiUsage(boolean useWifi) {
        boolean canWriteFlag = false;

        if (useWifi) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    canWriteFlag = true;
                    // Only need ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS on 6.0.0, regular permissions suffice on later versions
                } else if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.toString().equals("6.0.1")) {
                    canWriteFlag = true;
                    // Don't need ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS on 6.0.1, if we can positively identify it treat like 7+
                } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    // On M 6.0.0 (N+ or higher and 6.0.1 hit above), we need ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS to forceWifi.
                    canWriteFlag = Settings.System.canWrite(reactContext);
                    if (!canWriteFlag) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + reactContext.getPackageName()));
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        reactContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                if (((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) && canWriteFlag) || ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) && !(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M))) {
                    final ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) reactContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkRequest.Builder builder;
                    builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
                    //set the transport type do WIFI
                    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);


                    manager.requestNetwork(builder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                manager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                            } else {
                                //This method was deprecated in API level 23
                                ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
                            }
                            try {
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            manager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) reactContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                manager.bindProcessToNetwork(null);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

can anyone help to find why this is not working on Android pie?

Comment: Can you add errors?

Comment: no errors @Taym :(

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also affected by this and at wits end

Comment: Nevermind. My issue was that I was attempting to use forceWifiUsage(true) BEFORE connecting to the hotspot.

It *must* be run after connecting to the wifi network, and forceWifiUsage(false) must be run before disconnecting from the network